Downloaded font doesn't appear in Blender
SOLUTION: After unzipping the files into a folder, you still need to right click the unzipped file and choose 'install for all users', this not only puts the font directly into your windows/fonts folder, it also enables Blender to see it and utilize it as expected.
I downloaded a fun new font, 'Viking' from the internets. Unzipped it with no surprises. Installed it in my windows/fonts folder with all the others. Opened Blender, went to use the new font and it does not appear in my list. To test, I downloaded a second font from a different site. Unzipped and installed in windows/fonts, no surprises. But Blender can't see it either. The fonts are there when I look directly into Windows/fonts. I used another graphics program (Manga Studio), and the fonts are visible and fully useable, as expected. This morning I downloaded Blender version 4.1.1, started a brand new project, and the issue persists. It appears to be Blender specific. This usually means there is a button or setting in Blender I am unaware of, something like 'allow fun new fonts', but for the life of me I can't find it. I've run out of other brilliant ideas.
Any clews would be appreciated.

@Chris since he downloaded the new version, he should have restarted it. I also submitted an edit.

Does it work if you have them in a different folder? I download fonts into their own folder rather than installing them on windows and it seems to have no problem finding them when I go there. Tho I'm not using 4.1.1

Hello and welcome to BSE! I'm glad you've found a solution. Could you please post it as an Answer instead of adding the solution to the question? This separation suits the format of BSE and helps keep the site organized and easy to navigate for future users seeking solutions.
